# Content <section> not staying in place

Tags: html, css, responsive

I got this problem with my sections which is built up by a container, left menu, right menu and container:

```
#container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#leftmenu {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #111;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #202020;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#rightmenu {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #272727;
}
```

When I'm shrinking the window, the problem starts to appear:

The content box is appearing to the right (looks like beneath) the right menu, and is not shrinking with the others. How is this fixed?

HTML:

```
<section id="container">
    <section id="leftmenu">
      <section class="contenthead">
        <b style="font-weight: bold; color: #976535; text-align: center;"><center>HOVEDMENY</center></b>
      </section>

    </section>


    <section id="content">
      <section class="contenthead">&raquo; <? echo $page; ?></section>


    </section>

    <section id="rightmenu">
      <section class="contenthead">
        <b style="font-weight: bold; color: #976535; text-align: center;"><center>KOMMUNIKASJON</center></b>
    </section>


  </section>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Help, anyone?!?

Comment: please make a demo (jsfiddle/codepen etc) that demonstrates the issue you're having. it'll help us help you more easily :)

Comment: The thing is that i've placed the code into jsfiddle but the problem doesnt seem to occur there...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a fixed sidebar and a fluid content for this case in the desktop mode. Something like this might be a start for you...

```css
.main-content {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; position: relative; min-height: 200px; padding-left: 125px;}
.left-sidebar {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0px; width: 120px; background-color: #eee; height: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-sidebar"></div>
  <div class="right-fluid">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum libero iure facere quam iste, nostrum laborum in, dolorum beatae optio rem explicabo voluptates qui quos eius accusamus! Accusamus blanditiis, et!
  </div>
</div>
```

Try resizing the window in full screen and check it out.

**Update**

With your same code, it looks this way:

```css
#container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 200px;
}

#leftmenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #202020;
  min-height: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}

#rightmenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #272727;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <section id="leftmenu">
    <section class="contenthead">
      <b style="font-weight: bold; color: #976535;">HOVEDMENY</b>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section id="content">
    <section class="contenthead">&raquo; Page</section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, illo. Nulla saepe quasi sint nam, beatae adipisci labore mollitia. Minima assumenda corporis perspiciatis veritatis aut distinctio eligendi! Quam, deleniti, eveniet.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="rightmenu">
    <section class="contenthead">
      <b style="font-weight: bold; color: #976535; text-align: center;"><center>KOMMUNIKASJON</center></b>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: @FredrikChristensen Can you please tell clearly what doesn't work?

Comment: There is no right bar. Is there a way to fix the problem with the code I provided in the original post?

Comment: @FredrikChristensen You want both left and right bars? Yes, possible. Will do.